# How can you approximate $\sum_{i=0}^m \binom{n}{i}$?

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, asymptotics, binomial-coefficients, discrete-optimization

I am currently hearing a lecture about combinatorial optimization. I noticed that my professor often approximates $\binom{n}{m}$ by $n^m$ and I can understand why this can be done. Now I noticed that if he often approximates the expression $\sum_{i=0}^m \binom{n}{i}$ by $n^m$ as well, but I do not understand why this is true. Maybe he means $\sum_{i=0}^m \binom{n}{i}=O(n^m)$? But again I don't see why this holds. The best approximation I got so far is $\sum_{i=0}^m \binom{n}{i}\leq mn^m$.

Comment: This answer gives a proof that $\sum_{i=0}^m \binom{n}{i} \leq (n+1)^m$: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1610449/45008

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4365373/312

Comment: Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that since you approximate $\binom{n}{m}$ by $n^m$, in particular, we say that $\binom{n}{m}$ is $O(n^m)$. But in the similar fashion, $\binom{n}{m-1}$ is $O(n^{m-1})$ and so on. Thus you can approximate
$$\sum_{i=0}^m \binom{n}{i}= O(1)+O(n)+O(n^2)+\dots + O(n^{m-1})+O(n^m) = O(n^m)$$

Comment: Ah ok, so the $m$ get's swallowed as a constant!

Comment: Yes, you can think about it in that way as well.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Unless m is fixed and the limiting process only involves n, this simple analysis doesn't work.